# apache poi xlsx проблема с форматом

Tags: java, poi

есть такой код

```
String file = "C:\\Users\\Администратор\\Desktop\\ewq\\asd.xlsx";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File excel =  new File (file);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        String [][] data = new String [rowNum] [colNum];

        for(int i = 0; i <rowNum; i++){
            XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++){
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                String value = cell.toString();
                data[i][j] = value;
                System.out.println ("the value is " + value);
            }
        }
```

внутри excel файла

```
321312321321    
321312321321    
321312321321
```

числа с длиной 12++;

когда запускаю код почему стринг имеет такой формат `the value is 3.21312321321E11` , как можно получить правильный формат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `toString` дает лишь представление объекта в строковом виде, которое может не соответстовать вашим ожиданиям, для преобразования в строку в нужном виде лучше писать коду руками, например.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    File excel = new File(args[0]);
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel); XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);) {
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                String value = "";
                String type = "";
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    value = nf.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    type = "numeric";
                    break;
                case CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    type = "string";
                }
                data[i][j] = value;
                System.out.println("the value is '" + value + "' with type '" + type + "'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результатом такого кода будет (на моей машине)

```
the value is '321 312 321 321' with type 'numeric'
the value is '321 312 321 321' with type 'numeric'
the value is '321 312 321 321' with type 'numeric'
the value is '564 659 849 846' with type 'numeric'
```

Все значения представлены как числа, с разделителем разрядов в виде одного пробела.